# How to compute expectation of a exponentially distributed variable given the value of another variable?

Tags: exponential-distribution

I have 2 mutually independent random variables:

1. $s$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\lambda$: $s\sim F(\cdot|\lambda)$
2. $\epsilon_x$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\chi$: $\epsilon_x\sim F(\cdot|\chi)$

Define $x\equiv s-\epsilon_x$, $s_0\equiv \max\{x,0\}$. How do I compute the expectation of $s$, given a specific $s_0$? For example, How to compute $\mathbb{E}(s|s_0=2)$?

Comment: You mean $E(s|z_0=2)$?

Comment: @mpiktas no, $E(s|s_0=2)$.

Comment: @Xi'an This is just the first step of a research question. You can ignore $b$ and $z_0$. Given $s_0=2$,  we have $s-\epsilon_x=2$, then...? I'm sorry I'm very new to mathematical statistics.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm also very new to probability theory, sorry. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: This is a textbook calculation of conditional densities.

Comment: @mpiktas if it's that easy, could you please show me how to?